# Ubuntu 20.04 - How To Copy MP3 Music To An Old Apple iPod Nano Device?

Tags: ipod

I am running a current Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64Bit on an old Apple MacBook laptop computer.

How would I copy MP3 music to an old Apple iPod Nano device?

I have tried plugging in the iPod Nano into my Ubuntu computer and just copying over the MP3's.

MP3's are on the device now; but, when searching for the new MP3's on the device they are not shown?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried this in *years* but [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) used to work with iPods. You want software meant specifically to work with the proprietary iPod system and drag/drop doesn't work as regular MP3 files. It needs to be 'sync'ed and was quite a pain the last time I played around with it. Again, it has been years. Maybe someone has more recent info for you.

Answer (score 2):

Banshee used to be a good option to sync mp3 files to ipods. In my opinion it was the best Linux app to sync iPods because it was the only player that copied compilation albums exactly the way I like it. It seems however that Banshee is no longer available for Ubuntu 20.04. Other programs that you can use to copy files to the iPod are Rhytmbox, Strawberry and Amarok. These are all music players. Rhytmbox is the default music player and at least Strawberry is available in the Ubuntu Software store and is still maintained. Another option could be installing iTunes with Wine but I never managed to get that working. People say it is possible though.
Another application that you can use is gtkpod. This application is just for copying music to iPods and editing metadata.

Comment: I’m a fan of [Rhythmbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox) having recently used it to copy mp3 files and have them appear in an iPod Classic’s Artist/Album lists.